# Mobile Device Specific CSS not working

Tags: android, css, iphone, mobile, mobile-devices

I am trying to add following mobile specific header but it's not taking effect

```
#header{
  width:100%;
  padding:25px 0 20px 0;
  border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
  position: fixed !important;
  overflow: visible;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin:0;
  z-index: 99;
}

/* Diable border bottom on Mobile Devices */
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  #header {
    border-bottom:none;
  }
}
```

**+++ ADDED +++**

I am trying to remove a line displaying underneath Home Services Portfolio on mobile devices (screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQyCf.jpg), which works well on computer screens. The website is: modcansolutions.ca

Comment: Do you have meta `viewport` in your HTML? Please add more of your code.

Comment: @panther It's WordPress site

Comment: fine, and do you have meta `viewport` in your HTML?

Comment: @panther Yes. `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />`

Comment: @panther I am trying to remove a line displaying underneath Home Services Portfolio on mobile devices (screenshot: http://imgur.com/Q4pTNMG), which works well on computer screens. The website is: modcansolutions.ca

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line isn't just being caused by the `border-bottom` attribute, but also the `boxshadow` class which is giving a `box-shadow`, looking much like a border.

Simply assign `box-shadow: none` along with `border-bottom: none` into your css code and it this should fix it.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    #header {
        border-bottom: none;
        box-shadow: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this isn't working. Yon can test it here at http://www.responsinator.com/?url=www.modcansolutions.ca%2F

Comment: Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: I'm applying the styling to `#header` tag in my browser, its going through so maybe the problem lies with the `@media` call. You can try without the `-device` bit (so only `(max-width)`

Answer (score 0):

Edit: try to remove `-device`:

```
/* Diable border bottom on Mobile Devices */
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  #header {
    border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
  }
}
```

Edit #2: 
You're actually not assigning anything new. Your styling is the same as the original. `border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;` is also in the original CSS.

Comment: I have removed -device but no luck. I have updated `border-bottom:none;` for mobile specific device.

Comment: Which device are you testing on?

Comment: I am trying to check in iPhone. You can also try at http://www.responsinator.com/?url=www.modcansolutions.ca%2F